# Is it possible for CSS before and after tags to split hyperlinks?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to use CSS the ::before or ::after property to insert text BETWEEN opening and closing hyperlink tags?

For example: `<a href="#B>B Bring it Home</a>`

Could I insert a period after the B and before "Bring it Home"?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add a `<span/>`, then apply the before and after to that?

Ex.

```
<a href="#"><span class="i_p">B</span> Bring it Home</a>

.i_p::after { 
  content: ".";
}
```

Comment: I don't have access to insert/hard code another span. The link is wrapped in a UL and a div that have classes. So all I can do is add external CSS rules to the existing classes. That's why I'm asking. Looks like this.

    <div class="something"><ul class="somethingelse"><li><a href="#B>B Bring it Home</a></li></ul</div>